# value in array different inside useEffect and outside useEffect, ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**Value of "arrIds" array is different inside the useEffect and out the useEffect function.** 
*I think the way I am using "setArrIds([...arrValue]) is creating this problem, I am not sure."* 
I have shown the sample output as a comment.

```
import Menu from './data';
const App = () => {
const [values, setvalues] = useState([]);
  const [arrIds, setArrIds] = useState([]);
  var arrValue = [];
  var n = values.length;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", values);
    arrValue = [];
    Menu.filter(x => {
      if(values.includes(x.role)) {
        arrValue.push(x.id);
      }
      if(values.includes(x.level)) {
        arrValue.push(x.id);
      }
      if(x.languages.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
          if(x.languages.includes(values[i])) {
            arrValue.push(x.id);
          }
        }
      }
      if(x.tools.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
          if(x.tools.includes(values[i])) {
            arrValue.push(x.id);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    console.log("new array of id", arrValue);
    arrValue = [...new Set(arrValue)];
    console.log("new array of id without repetition", arrValue);//output: [1, 2, 4]
    if(arrValue) {
      setArrIds([...arrValue]);
      console.log("arrIds 1", arrIds); //output: [1, 4]
    }
    console.log("arrIds 2", arrIds);//output: [1, 4]
  }, [values]);

  console.log("arrIds 3", arrIds);//output: [1, 2, 4]
}
```

The data.js file contains array of objects:

```
export default [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": Photosnap,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "company": "Manage",
    "logo": manage,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Fullstack Developer",
    "role": "Fullstack",
    "level": "Midweight",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "Remote",
    "languages": ["Python"],
    "tools": ["React"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "company": "Account",
    "logo": account,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Junior",
    "postedAt": "2d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["React", "Sass"]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "company": "MyHome",
    "logo": myhome,
    "new1": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Junior",
    "postedAt": "5d ago",
    "contract": "Contract",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "company": "Loop Studios",
    "logo": loopstudios,
    "new1": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Software Engineer",
    "role": "FullStack",
    "level": "Midweight",
    "postedAt": "1w ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "Worldwide",
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["Ruby", "Sass"]
  }
]
```

I tried using `setArrIds(arrIds => [...arrIds, ...arrValue]);` , I got the same response. Is there any other way.
*This is creating a lot of problem in my code, **PLEASE HELP ME** with this.*

Comment: You have not provided any [depencies to useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: This is the expected behavior, you need to as arrIds to you dependency array to get the latest version of it.

Comment: I added it to my dependency array, still getting the same results

Comment: you do realize that you're going to update on useEffect, and then only on the next render it will be updated, correct?

Comment: also, why are you using filter to set arrValue? that code seems very wrong

Comment: @iagowp i changed the filter to map, that was by mistake and yeah i realize it will be rendered on the next rendered, so what do i do to make it right?

Comment: If i add `arrIds` to my useEffect depedencies, I am not able to open my console at all, cause errors are poping up every second when i add `arrIds` to my useEffect depedencies.

Comment: what error do you get?